# need help resolving workflow issues with private cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on a private pod, with a few other engineers. This pod is used by a few projects.

I've set up the private podspec repo properly, and everything works, but my git tags are climbing at a rapid pace. I feel like there must be a better way to approach this, just unsure about how to proceed. Here's what I'm doing.

1. Change code to private pod.
2. pod spec lint.

Assuming this succeeds, then

1. add git tag to repo for private pod.
2. change version in podspec file, and change tag in podspec file.
3. pod repo push ....

Then in my main app that uses this:
6. pod update

While this all works, it does cause me to escalate my git tags very rapidly, even a good amount of these tags, and pod versions, will never be used. Also, if another project does a "pod update", then it will get this latest version, even though I haven't tested it fully on my target app.

Just wondering if there's a workflow where I could use my private pod, make changes to it, and test it with my target app, and once I'm satisfied, then tag & push the podspec.

I guess basically, I want to "branch" my podspec until I'm sure it's ready, and then only release it to the group by performing the versioning & tagging.

Thanks for any tips on a good workflow.

-Dan.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use tags to reference your code in pod file. You can also use repo 'head' and once the code is stable create a tag and use it. For reference [Using Pod file.](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) Look for `pod 'Objection', :head` in the document and read the relevant part.